# Recording the amount of replacements when using ActiveDocument

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to have the amount of replacements made by this word macro displayed in the status bar. I am not sure how to get the replacements made as an integer.

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = xSelection
    .Replacement.Text = myValue
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find with *wbReplaceAll* don't return count of replacement.
You must calculate it himself. One of method  you can  [see there](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/GetNoOfReplacements.htm)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.